# Oracle Error while executing query -ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE FRA_SAP
SET FRA_SAP.ENT_ATTRIBUTES = FE.ENT_ATTRIBUTES
FROM FRA_SAP FES
INNER JOIN FRA_ENTITIES FE
    ON FES.ID = FE.ID
```

I am getting the below error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
```

Comment: What is this trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can't use an inner join as part of an update query in Oracle, for some odd reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support `FROM` or `JOIN` (generally) in `UPDATE`.  The equivalent is:

```
UPDATE FRA_SAP
    SET FRA_SAP.ENT_ATTRIBUTES = (SELECT FE.ENT_ATTRIBUTES
                                  FROM FRA_ENTITIES FE
                                  WHERE FES.ID = FE.ID
                                 )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM FRA_ENTITIES FE
                  WHERE FES.ID = FE.ID
                 );
```

Note:  If there are multiple matching rows in `FRA_ENTITIES` then this query will return an error.  The equivalent query in SQL Server -- using your syntax -- would use an arbitrary matching row for the update.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using SQL Server update join syntax, which won't work on Oracle.  One version that would work uses a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE FRA_SAP fes
SET ENT_ATTRIBUTES = (SELECT fe.ENT_ATTRIBUTES
                      FROM FRA_ENTITIES fe
                      WHERE fes.ID = fe.ID);
```

The following, which is closer to a true update join, might also work:

```
UPDATE 
(
    SELECT fes.ENT_ATTRIBUTES AS OLD, fe.ENT_ATTRIBUTES AS NEW
    FROM FRA_SAP fes
    INNER JOIN FRA_ENTITIES fe
        ON fes.ID = fe.ID
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW;
```

Comment: Answer given 5 minutes _before_ Gordon posted almost the same thing.